# Octopus Ride how much +G force in upward Jerk?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, estimation

This is a version of the Octopus Ride here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8flmhIAKTvQ

They call it Hip Hop but really it is what you call it in other places, I felt my left Butt Cheek or Thigh cramp up cause I was at the left

Question: How many + G's might be in this ride? If you guys can check the 0: 20 mark or the 2: 07 mark where the ride jerks up and down?

I know though that 0 G-ish or weightlessness and certainly moments of Free Fall are the selling point of this ride,

However, is it possible there are +G's? I mean I know you can't give me an accurate number, certainly there is prolly 0.5 +G's when you rise in an elevator, and knowing my Left Butt or Thigh hurt, there may be some G forces around here momentarily, can you guys Eye Ball the ride and give an estimate of how much G's we pull when we ride this?